# Can I set attr values like numbers in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have one doubt Can I set attr value like a number...example

```
<div data-check="1"></div>
```

This is the correct method or not? Some people are telling like do not set numbers to data attribute value. So I am asking you.

Comment: You can do that, why not!

Comment: who says it lol

Comment: It depends on the attribute. Data-attributes are always converted to string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: So above my code is correct?

Comment: Your code is correct. Just be sure to parse that value to the proper type if you are going to use it for some calculations or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can just like you wrote in your question. For more information can read [this great article](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-why-use-html5-custom-data-attributes/).

```
<li data-type="veg" data-distance="2miles" data-identifier="10318">
  Salad King
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can set any value to HTML attributes as you required. By using `HTML data-* Attributes` as:

```
<ul>
  <li data-item-one="1">One</li>
  <li data-item-two="2">Two</li> 
  <li data-item-three="2">Three</li> 
</ul>
```

The `data-* attributes` are used to store custom data private to the page or application.

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)